# How to break line automatically after slash?

Tags: javascript, html, css, line-breaks

I have a `div` on the left and a `canvas` on the right, both filling the whole screen. Depending on the item I point to in the canvas, I show some information on the div (`element.innerHTML = '...'`). The problem is, some texts are too long and get hidden to the right side of the div (I don't want to use a scrollbar).

Usually the long text is composed of slash-separated names, like `name1/name2/name3`. If the slash separated the text to a new line, my problem would be solved, but it doesn't. Some possible solutions would be:

1) substitute '/' with '/ ', but it gets ugly if the text fits in a single line. For the same reason, I can't add `\n` to the html. Also, this text is meant to be copied, so even adding some styling to hide the space is not what I need.

2) substitute '/' with another separator character that automatically breaks the line (are hyphens my only friend here? They don't look appropriate for my case).

3) use `overflow-wrap: break-word`, but it will break the word in the middle, and I prefer it to be broken right after the slash.

4) automatically increase the div width without messing with the canvas position and size (`body` is using `flex-direction:row`). That would be the best solution, I think, because it would also solve the rarest cases where the problem is not with the slash.

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5ot7Lgm/30/) to illustrate, you can see that some slashes break the text, while others don't (and the text breaks before the slash, which I think is ugly. Anyway, if I have to accept the text being broken before the slash, it still needs to break before ALL the necessary slashes!)

HTML

```
<body>
<div id='data'>
  <button onclick='c()'>
  Get Text
  </button><br>
  <br>
  Default text.<br>
  <br>
  <span id='text'></span>
</div>
<canvas id='canv'>
</canvas>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#data {
    padding:10px;
  background-color: #CCF;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#canv {
  background-color: #CFC;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var data = document.getElementById('data');
var canv = document.getElementById('canv');
canv.width = window.innerWidth - data.offsetWidth;
canv.height = window.innerHeight;

function c() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  text.innerHTML = 'longname1/longname2/longname3/longname4';
}
```

Comment: There's a possibility to include the running code *right* in your question instead of leaving a link. Please do that.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, neither I did downvote.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, why isn't this question about programming?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the slashes using span and apply some styling to make them close to text:

```js
var data = document.getElementById('data');
var canv = document.getElementById('canv');
canv.width = window.innerWidth - data.offsetWidth;
canv.height = window.innerHeight;

function c() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  text.innerHTML = 'longname1<span>/</span> longnam<span>/</span> longname3<span>/</span> longname4<span>/</span> lllllllll<span>/</span> lon<span>/</span> aa';
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#data {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #CCF;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#canv {
  background-color: #CFC;
}

#text span {
  letter-spacing: -4px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='data'>
    <button onclick='c()'>
  Get Text
  </button>
  default text 
  <br>
  <br>
    <div id='text'></div>
  </div>
  <canvas id='canv'>
</canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: That's a workaround, but the spaces after the slash are copied and pasted elsewhere. And these data are meant to be copied. The fourth solution would be the best, I'll edit the question to explain this. Sorry for not explaining before.

Comment: @Rodrigo yes but the (4) solution implies a lot of calculation if the text gonna be dynamic

Comment: I shouldn't hate CSS as much as I do. Thinking a little more about it, I just remembered there's a `min-width` property. It solved my problem in the end.